# Type 'IStateTypes' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. TS2488 [React, TypeScript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Currently I am trying to make a global state in React Hooks but encounter a problem.

[image]

Problem I have now is that it is nagging about **[Symbol.iterator](**. Not sure how to fix that. Since I am currently experimenting with React Hooks to create a global state. The problem occurs when I try to move the useReducer to a separate Store.tsx file.

Here the link to snippet:

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/poker-game-react-hooks)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in how you are defining your `context` in Store.tsx. You give `createContext` the initial value of initialState, so it infers the type of the context to be `IStateTypes`, but then you pass the provider a value of `[state, dispatch]`, which obviously is not an `IStateTypes`

Change your `createContext` to give it a type that matches what you are passing into the value, something like:

```
export const Context = createContext<[IStateTypes,Dispatch<any>]>([initialState,()=>{}]);
```

Comment: What is `IStateTypes` in this usage? If I have a `string` type state variable, can I also use `<[string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>]>`? Or is the usage of `IStateTypes` recommended?

Comment: `IStateTypes` is the just the type of the initial state. If the state was a string then yes you would want to use `<string>` instead